# How to use spinner in robotium?

Tags: android, spinner, robotium

Register.xml file,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/spinner_relay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/fd_register_header"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dm_5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dm_10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dm_10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dm_5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_background" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fp_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dm_10dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/icondown"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:padding="@dimen/dm_10dp"
        android:text="Select city"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dm_18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

if i used this code,

```
int pos = solo.getCurrentSpinners().get(0).getSelectedItemPosition();
```

getting error,

> cannot resolve  symbol getCurrentSpinner

Comment: show your full code please .

Comment: There is no such method 'getCurrentSpinners' in Solo class. You can use isSpinnerTextSelected method

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following codes for working with Spinners and this is what worked for me

```
solo.pressSpinnerItem(0, -5);     //selects the item in the spinner
```

Or

```
solo.isSpinnerTextSelected(0,"Items")    //checks whether the spinner item is selected
```